# Update PK columns in table having clustered keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with tables that have clustered primary keys.  I believe the term I picked up on is use of a Natural Key.  The frontend to the SQL database is programmed to affect changes to all related foreign key tables for the 3,000 selected values which I want to modify. It takes about 13 seconds per change.  I have a need to do this in a much shorter timeframe if possible.

The reason for doing this is prep work to migrate to a new CMMS program.

I found reference for use of ON UPDATE CASCADE, but I am not certain this applies.

Among many references, I used the following:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/it-IT/23294919-3e6a-4146-a70d-66fa155ed1b3/update-primary-key-column-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql

An example of 2 of the 15 tables having the same named [EQNUM] column follows. Table A is the table that is first modified using the frontend.   I left out many columns for each table:

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
    [EQNUM] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EQNUM] ASC)
)
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

CREATE TABLE B 
(
    [EQNUM] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ColA] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,[ColB] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ColC] [varchar](30) NOT NULL, [ColD] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ColE] [varchar](30) NOT NULL, [ColF] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ColG] [varchar](11) NOT NULL,[ColH] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ColI] [datetime] NOT NULL,[ColJ] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ColK] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_B] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EQNUM] ASC, 
                               [ColA] ASC,[ColB] ASC,[ColC] ASC,[ColD] ASC,[ColE] ASC,
                               [ColF] ASC,[ColG] ASC,[ColH] ASC,[ColI] ASC,[ColJ] ASC)
)
```

An example of 1 of 4 sets of UPDATE queries, for which I believe the added first and last `ALTER TABLE` lines would allow me to affect the update:

```
ALTER TABLE A NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [PK_EQUIP]

UPDATE A
SET [EQNUM] = REPLACE([EQNUM],'-B','-B0')
WHERE [EQNUM] LIKE '%-A[1-9][0-5][0-9]-%' OR
      [EQNUM] LIKE '%-A[1-9][A-F][0-5][0-9]-%' OR

ALTER TABLE A CHECK CONSTRAINT [PK_EQUIP]

ALTER TABLE A NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [PK_B]

UPDATE B
SET [EQNUM] = REPLACE([EQNUM],'-B','-B0')
WHERE [EQNUM] LIKE '%-A[1-9][0-5][0-9]-%' OR
      [EQNUM] LIKE '%-A[1-9][A-F][0-5][0-9]-%' OR

ALTER TABLE A CHECK CONSTRAINT [PK_B]
```

Is it this simple, or am I missing something? Is there a better way?

Comment: I might make the case that a natural key is maybe not a good fit here. When you have to change the key like this it is usually a sign that a natural key is not a good choice. Sort like email. It kind of makes sense as a natural key but it doesn't work well because people change them.

Comment: You have horrible primary keys.

Comment: Agreed... thus the migration to a new system.  I won't mention the vendor that provided this system.